General form of functions with $\hat{f}(n) = 0$ for all $|n| \geq 2$

How to determine the general form of functions with $\hat{f}(n) = 0$ for all $|n| \geq 2$?

Here $\hat{f}(n)$ denotes the $n$-th Fourier coefficient of Riemann integrable function $f$. It is also assumed that $f$ is $T$-periodic defined on $[0,T]$.
I know that $f$ should be of form
$$
A\sin \frac{2\pi t}{T} + B\cos \frac{2\pi t}{T}. 
$$
However, I do not know how to show this. First I used the fact that
$$
\int_0^T \! f(x)\,e^{-\frac{2inx\pi}{T}}\,dx = 0,
$$
for $|n| \geq 2$. How should I continue from here?
Thank for your time.

If the function $f$ is equal to its Fourier series, then we have
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\hat{f}(n)e^{\frac{2\pi i nx}{T}}\\
&=\sum_{|n|< 2}\hat{f}(n)e^{\frac{2\pi i nx}{T}}\\
&=\hat{f}(0)+\hat{f}(1)e^{\frac{2\pi i x}{T}}+\hat{f}(-1)e^{\frac{-2\pi i x}{T}}
\end{align*}
Now use Euler's formula.

For a Riemann integrable or even  continuous function its Fourier series may be not convergent pointwise. We can overcome that obstacle as follows. WLOG we may assume that $T=2\pi.$ Consider the function $$g(x)=f(x)-\widehat{f}(0)-\widehat{f}(1)e^{inx}-\widehat{f}(-1)e^{-inx}$$ Then $\widehat{g}(n)=0$ for every $n.$  Therefore $g=0,$ by the theorem that the Fourier coefficients determine the function.
